# Highcharts multiple axis with custom labels

Tags: highcharts, label, multiple-axes

I have a Highcharts waterfall chart with two x-Axis:

```
 xAxis: [{
    useHTML: true,
    categories: ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR']
    },
   {
    tickWidth: 0,
    categories: [0, 10, 12, 1],
    labels: {
      style: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
     formatter: function(){
       return '$ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,1)
     }
   }
 }],
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/er1187/8gwzcbsk/4/

I am also trying to add custom labels on top of each bar (red labels): https://jsfiddle.net/er1187/pqfa0Lpm/

I am struggling to show all three (3) on one chart, when I add the custom labels the second axis disappears. Any way to have all three?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer is that your second xAxis disappears because you are replacing it with your data labels version of the xAxis.

Comment: And a simple demo with all three axes: https://jsfiddle.net/8gwzcbsk/5/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add all three by linking two categories:

```
{
    linkedTo: 0,
    categories: ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE','FOUR']
},
{   linkedTo: 0,
    categories: ['FIVE', 'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT']
}
```

See edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/er1187/pqfa0Lpm/